# platform.registerBackButtonAction is not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to override the back button functionality in angular2 on ionic2 platform . This is my code written in app.component.ts file.

```
constructor(platform: Platform,public myapp: IonicApp) {
    this.pltform=platform;
    this.app=myapp;
    platform.ready().then(() => {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
          Splashscreen.hide();
          platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event){
            window.alert("back button pressed");
            let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
            if (nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
                  nav.pop();
            }else{
                 this.platform.exitApp(); //Exit from app
            }
         });
    }
}
```

on back button click it enters in  registerBackButtonAction method only once. and the this.app.getActiveNav(); gives undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a regular function callback. The `this` refers to the function and not the class.
Ue arrow function

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction((event)=>{
            window.alert("back button pressed");
            let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
            if (nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
                  nav.pop();
            }else{
                 this.platform.exitApp(); //Exit from app
            }
         });
```

Or use `self`

```
let self = this;    
platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event){
                window.alert("back button pressed");
                let nav = self.app.getActiveNav();
                if (nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
                      nav.pop();
                }else{
                     this.platform.exitApp(); //Exit from app
                }
             });
```

Comment: will this code work for only one page or all the page

Comment: it should work for all pages.. platform is a single object for entire app and you are registering its back button

Comment: so i want to make the app close only on home page if use this code will it solve my issue

Comment: it will make an app wide change so wont be only for the specific page but will take effect after navigating to home page. Also [check here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) its for android hardware back button and wont work for IOS.

Comment: `let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();` what this line does i have tried many times i am getting errror on the `app` you have any idea

Comment: I have just copied the code you have posted and placed in my home page. Want to know is there any thing I have to import to avoid app error I have imported platform similar to that do I have to import any thing to app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134462/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).

Comment: the statement 'let nav = self.app.getActiveNav();' is not executing. and the platform.registerBackButtonAction is not involked when i had clicked on back button second time.